# header menu 100% width and inline divs, Menu links align right, title left, all in white except the "active" link that must be transparent

Tags: css

This is what I want:
http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/9764/menuhn.gif

The grey area is a background image with the property `background-size: cover;` that is shown in HOME button. All the rest is white.

To make it responsive, so it can be *browsable* in mobile devices, I would like that the link buttons go behind each others has the window narrows. BTW, the order of the right link buttons are inverted.

this is what i get so far:

http://jsfiddle.net/Emaster/Wmwu4/

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header_left_margin"></div>

    <div id="header_title"> 
        <h3><a href="index.html">title</a></h3>
    </div>

    <div id="header_right_margin"></div>
    <div id="menu">
     <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background-image: url(http://solfar.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/background-1024x682.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

#header_title{
    border:1px solid blue;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}

#header_title,
#header_title h3,
#header_title h3 a{
    display: inline;
}

#menu ul li{
      float:right;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
      border:1px solid red;
      background-color: white;  
}

#menu ul li.active {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#menu ul{
 display: inline;
}

#menu,
#menu ul,
#menu ul li{
  display: inline;
}

#header_right_margin{
    display: inline;
    float:right;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid green;
        background-color: white;
}

#header_left_margin{
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    height: 50px;
    border:1px solid green;
        background-color: white; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made this menu for you (next time you'll have to pay :). I should mention that you don't need to use `display: inline` and `float` together as `float` will dominate anyway. Here is [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wmwu4/1/). Another thought - use plugins for responsive designs. They already have built-in solutions. You can try [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Morpheus. However, the grey area must be an image with a no fixed width (`background-size: cover;`). So, in `#menu ul li.active`, `background-color` in your solution can't be `grey`, and if is set as `transparent` it will be white because the parent div `header` has a white background.